# Can I skip O365 email checkin when first joining sharepoint site?

Tags: office-365, login

So whenever I open a Google Chrome with my company's intranet, the dialog windows from Office shows up and want me to log with my company email:

[image]

Can I somehow set to *remember* me or skip it? When you have to fill it for the 20th time in a same day, it gets quite annoying. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-apps-secure-sign-in-ex/ggjhpefgjjfobnfoldnjipclpcfbgbhl

In addition, it will depend on Azure AD policies and if they have a session timeout.

Comment: I can't check if it works because company administrator blocked this extension. Thanks anyway!